# Why am I getting a Key Error with a loc statement on a dataframe with a known column that prints out correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror, pandas-loc

I get a key error on a column that exists under the name that I attempt to use in a `loc` statement.

```
product = products_df.loc[products_df['product_id'] == 6]
```

Before the `loc` statement, I printed out the first five rows of the data frame.

```
print(products_df.head())

<<<<<<< HEAD
NaN product_id product_name                                       aisle_id department_id        price
0   1          Chocolate Sandwich Cookies                         61       19                    2.99
1   2          All-Seasons Salt                                   104      13                    7.99
2   3          Robust Golden Unsweetened Oolong Tea               94       7                     2.99
3   4          Smart Ones Classic Favorites Mini Rigatoni With... 38       1                     2.99
```

*It is hard to tell from the way the dataframe wraps here.
So the column exists, but the `loc` statement gives me a key error.

The error I get specifically is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scottmcmahan/.local/share/virtualenvs/inventory-mh3G_UMG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in 
    pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in 
    pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in 
    pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in 
    pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'product_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter, use `query` method as it will produce a new dataframe

```
products = products_df.query('product_id == 6')
```

If that doesn't work please provide a way to replicate.